# Why does 1I planetary approach suite occupy a class 8 space?

Tags: elite-dangerous

[image]

If you have a 2E cargo rack in a size 4 slot, you can buy a 4E cargo rack to replace the 2E cargo rack in that slot - providing greater cargo carrying space.

It seems my 1I planetary approach suite only occupies 1/8th of the available room in its slot. I can't find a way to move this planetary approach suite to a smaller slot so that I can take advantage of the size 8 slot for something bigger (more cargo etc)

I thought the big number at left is the size of a slot in which you can outfit various modules. I thought the solid dots underneath corresponds to the space actually filled by the current module and open dots (circles) indicate unused space in the slot.

Have I misunderstood how the size of modules relates to the size of internal ship slots?

Comment: What's most amusing about this is that a size 8 slot is normally large enough to hold small craft like the Sidewinder or Eagle. Yet these craft also have size 8 slots for the Planetary Approach Suite. It's like we're using Time-Lordian "Bigger on the Inside" tech or something. An 8E Cargo Rack can hold 256 tons of cargo, yet somehow there's an equivalent-sized slot in the 25-ton Sidey now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a dedicated slot that cannot be used for anything other than a planetary approach suite. Notice how the other compartments say "internal compartment", whereas this one says "planetary approach suite".

These slots were added in 2.0, and didn't change any of the other ship internals. That is, this did not add an extra slot, nor did it take up a slot that was previously free for any internal component.

Not sure why they made them higher than class 1 on some ships. It might allow only certain ships to perform atmospheric landings in the future, but that's mere specualtion.